# Breaking URL after HTTPS and Trailing Slash Add via htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

Below is recent added htaccess code that is meant to add a trailing slash and HTTPS to my URLs e.g. from http://www.example.com.au/rest to https://www.example.com.au/rest/

```
RewriteEngine On

#Trailing backslash
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

If a link is click for the site it some times does this: https://www.example.com.au/more_of_the_url/last_of_url/?/[QSA,L]/last_of_url/

The correct URL is: https://www.example.com.au/more_of_the_url/last_of_url/

Whats going wrong here? Please help

MORE INFO:
So I've made a solution that gets the user to the page but the URL is still incorrect. By moving the following code to the bottom of the htaccess file the redirects work and they land on a real page.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* [QSA,L]
```

This now lands the user on: https://www.example.com.au/more_of_the_url/last_of_url/?/more_of_the_url/last_of_url/

This is what it should look like:
https://www.example.com.au/more_of_the_url/last_of_url/

Comment: **RewriteRule .* [QSA,L]** there is a problem in this line,you omitted the Rewrite target, [QSA,L] is in the rewrite target ,thats why it is appending it to the url. also the order of your rules is incorrect.

Comment: Can you show me how to fix that?